# How to change var from interface.System.Linq.IQueryable<out T> to class System.Collections.generic.List<T>

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var allWorkorders =

            (from wo in context.WORKORDERs
            join wot in context.WORKORDERTYPEs on wo.wot_oi equals wot.wotyoi
            join pri in context.PRIORITies on wo.prio_oi equals pri.priooi
            join s in context.SITEs on wo.BEparn_oi equals s.siteoi
            where wo.audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= now.Year - 3 && wo.audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= 2006
                && wo.audt_created_dttm < timeframe && (s.id == "NM" || s.id == "TH") &&
                (wo.clsdt_date ?? new DateTime(3000, 01, 01)) < DateTime.Now
            group pri by new {s.id, pri.prioid, MonthNum = (wo.clsdt_date ?? new DateTime(3000, 01, 01)).Year * 100 +
                (wo.clsdt_date ?? new DateTime(3000, 01, 01)).Month} into groupItem
            orderby groupItem.Key.MonthNum, groupItem.Key.id
            select new {groupItem.Key.id, groupItem.Key.prioid, groupItem.Key.MonthNum, Unit = groupItem.Count()});

            allWorkorders.GroupBy(x => new { x.id, x.MonthNum }).Select(x => new {x.Key.id, x.Key.MonthNum,
            Denominator = x.Sum(y => y.Unit), Numerator = x.Where(y => SqlMethods.Like(y.prioid, "1%") || 
            SqlMethods.Like(y.prioid, "6%")).Sum(y => y.Unit), Data_Indicator = DATA_INDICATOR,
            Budgeted = budgetedPlannedOutageHrs, Industry_Benchmark = INDUSTRY_BENCHMARK,
            Comments = comments, Executive_Comments = executiveComments, 
            Fleet_Exec_Comments = fleetExecComments}).ToList();
```

I want to create a for loop:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < allWorkorders.Count; counter++)
{
    var item = allWorkorders[counter];
    ......
```

However, I get the following error:  " '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'"

So even though I have allWorkorders going to ToList() it's not being recognized as a list.

What am I doing wrong?  I have done this in the past, the biggest difference being that in the past cases my ToList was at the end of the select statement.

Comment: You should rethink this code. If it is so complex that you didn't see that the result wasn't assigned to a value, it is obviously too complicated

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos:  It's not that I didn't know that it wasn't assigned to a value.  I mistakenly believed it was assigned to  allWorkorders.

Comment: That's my point. If you can't see this easily, it's probably too complicated. I didn't see this either until Resharper indented the code

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie don't put a space between @ and the users name.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you look at the comments on my answer, it is not that the OP did not see that the assign did not take place, the OP did not know the assignment was required.

Comment: @cadrell0 thank you for the link.  You've taught me two things today!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToList() returns a result. You need something like

```
var newList = allWorkorders.GroupBy(x => ...).Select(x => ...).ToList();
```

Comment: @ Brannon: Thank you for the help.  Since you were the first one to answer I will give you credit for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to use the LINQ extension method method `Count()` rather than the `List<T>.Count`

The reason it is doing this is you are not assigning the results of `ToList()` to anything.  This whole statement is basically ignored because you are not using the return value

```
allWorkorders.GroupBy(x => new { x.id, x.MonthNum }).Select(x => new {x.Key.id, x.Key.MonthNum,
Denominator = x.Sum(y => y.Unit), Numerator = x.Where(y => SqlMethods.Like(y.prioid, "1%") || 
SqlMethods.Like(y.prioid, "6%")).Sum(y => y.Unit), Data_Indicator = DATA_INDICATOR,
Budgeted = budgetedPlannedOutageHrs, Industry_Benchmark = INDUSTRY_BENCHMARK,
Comments = comments, Executive_Comments = executiveComments, 
Fleet_Exec_Comments = fleetExecComments}).ToList();
```

Comment: @ cadrell0: I see.  I mistakenly believe that the allWorkorders.GroupBy code was assigned to allWorkOrders.  Once I created a new var datatype for that code it worked fine.  I guess I don't understand why it wasn't recognized by allWorkorders though.

Comment: LINQ methods (GroupBy, Where, Select, ToList, etc) do not modify the collection they operate on.  They return a new collection.  This is similar to the behavior of string methods Replace, Substring, Trim, and others.

Comment: @ cadrell0:  I did not know that.  Until I began this internship a couple of weeks ago I had never even heard of LINQ, so I am still struggling with understanding it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign the second line (the one with ToList()) on it to anything.  You ended the assignment of allWorkOrders with: "Unit = groupItem.Count()});"

Dropping on ToList() will make it return a list, but since you didn't assign it to anything it immediately goes out of scope and you lose it.

Comment: @ YYY:  Thank you for the help and the explaination

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a foreach loop instead or add the () to Count, `for (int counter = 0; counter < allWorkorders.Count(); counter++)`. In this case Count is not a property but a Linq extension method that you're calling on an IEnumerable, which is why it complains about a method group when you give it just `.Count` instead of calling the method `.Count()`.

Also, you have two separate statements there and don't appear to be storing the part which you are performing the `.ToList()` against anywhere.

Comment: @Brannon No, no it doesn't. See the second paragraph.